# sum += hand[i] works, sum += handNew[i] doesn't - why?

Tags: javascript

This program will take cards in a hand of Golf (the card game) and add them up to get the final score. As shown, all face cards and aces are worth 10 points.

This works, but I have no idea why. I needed `handNew = [];`
In my first `for` loop, I'm using `handNew = hand[i];`. But in my second `for` loop, I tried using `sum += handNew[i]`, but that doesn't work. Only `sum += hand[i]` works.

Could someone please tell me why? I got the program to work, but no idea why it works the way it does.

```js
function golfScore(hand) {
  var hand = [5, 2, "King", 3, 1, "Queen"];
  var handNew = [];
  var sum = 0;

  for (var i = 0; i < hand.length; i++) {
    if (hand[i] === "King" || hand[i] === "Queen" || hand[i] ===
      "Jack" || hand[i] === "Ace") {
      hand[i] = 10;
    }
    handNew += hand[i];
  }
  for (i = 0; i < hand.length; i++) {
    sum += hand[i];
  }

  document.getElementById('golfDiv').innerHTML = sum;
}
```

```html
This program will calculate your golf score.
<button type="button" onclick="golfScore()">Calculate 
                        GolfScore</button>
<div id="golfDiv"></div>
```

Comment: Ew. Arrays should not be `+=`d. But regardless, you don't need it, `handNew` is never referenced elsewhere

Answer (score 0):

If you change `handNew += hand[i];` to `handNew[i] = hand[i];` then your program will work with `sum += handNew[i];` in the second loop. The reason for this is that when you used the `+=` operator in the first loop the value of `hand[i]` was being treated as a string. However, the presence of `handNew` Is not needed in this program and will run fine with just `hand`.

Answer (score 0):

In the first iteration of your first `for` loop, you're changing the type of `handNew` from an array to a string when you do `handNew += hand[i]`. On each subsequent iteration, the `+=` operator will now perform string concatenation instead of addition.

```js
let arrPlusNum = []
arrPlusNum += 10
console.log(`Value: ${arrPlusNum}, Type: ${typeof arrPlusNum}`)

let strPlusNum = "12"
strPlusNum += 3
console.log(`Value: ${strPlusNum}, Type: ${typeof strPlusNum}`)
```

You can see what happens at each iteration in your `for` loop below.

```js
function golfScore(hand) {
  var hand = [5, 2, "King", 3, 1, "Queen"];
  var handNew = [];
  var sum = 0;

  for (var i = 0; i < hand.length; i++) {
    if (hand[i] === "King" || hand[i] === "Queen" || hand[i] ===
      "Jack" || hand[i] === "Ace") {
      hand[i] = 10;
    }
    handNew += hand[i];
    console.log(`V: ${handNew}, Type: ${typeof handNew}`);
  }
}
```

```html
<button type="button" onclick="golfScore()">
  Calculate GolfScore
</button>
```

---

Now, answering the question:

> But in my second `for` loop, I tried using `sum += handNew[i]`, but that doesn't work. Only `sum += hand[i]` works. Could someone please tell me why?

`sum += handNew[i]` doesn't work as you expect because `handNew` is now a string. Accessing the index on a string will give you the character at that index position. You then perform string concatenation on `sum` since you are adding together a number and string.

```js
function golfScore(hand) {
  var hand = [5, 2, "King", 3, 1, "Queen"];
  var handNew = [];
  var sum = 0;

  for (var i = 0; i < hand.length; i++) {
    if (hand[i] === "King" || hand[i] === "Queen" || hand[i] ===
      "Jack" || hand[i] === "Ace") {
      hand[i] = 10;
    }
    handNew += hand[i];
  }
  console.log(`Value: ${handNew}, Type: ${typeof handNew}`)
  for (i = 0; i < hand.length; i++) {
    console.log(`Value: ${handNew[i]}`)
    sum += handNew[i];
  }

  document.getElementById('golfDiv').innerHTML = sum;
}
```

```html
<p>This program will calculate your golf score.</p>
<button type="button" onclick="golfScore()">
  Calculate GolfScore
</button>
<div id="golfDiv"></div>
```

---

Here is an alternative solution to your function. It uses [`Array.prototype.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce), [`Array.prototype.includes()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes), and [`const`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/const).

```js
function golfScore() {
  // This array contains cards that are the value of 10.
  const value10 = ["King", "Queen", "Jack", "Ace"]
  const hand = [5, 2, "King", 3, 1, "Queen"]

  sum = hand.reduce((currentSum, currentCard) => {
    if (value10.includes(currentCard)) currentSum += 10
    else currentSum += currentCard
    
    return currentSum
  })
  document.getElementById('golfDiv').innerHTML = sum;
}
```

```html
<p>This program will calculate your golf score.</p>
<button type="button" onclick="golfScore()">
  Calculate GolfScore
</button>
<div id="golfDiv"></div>
```